# missing file require architecture i386 and x86_64 on simulator but working fine on device

Tags: ios

I have added TurnOutNow library which contain EASDK.h and libEventAnalytics.a

My project & TurnOutNow library have reachability.m file.

So it was giving following errror on build :

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Reachability in: /Users/achavan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Meeting_Caddie-bbzedidjjyellubhnftrohiumzog/Build/Intermediates/Meeting Caddie.build/Debug-iphoneos/Meeting Caddie.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Reachability.o /Work_Theme_iPhone/New M_Caddie/Eventpedia_Beta/iOS_Eventpedia/TurnOutNow_SDK/libEventAnalytics.a(Reachability.o) ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
```

I searched on stackoverflow and found that removing reachability.m from build phases would work.

But then it was giving following error:

```
(null): "_kReachabilityChangedNotification", referenced from:

(null): -[AppDelegate setUpRechability] in AppDelegate.o

(null): +[ASIHTTPRequest registerForNetworkReachabilityNotifications] in ASIHTTPRequest.o

(null): +[ASIHTTPRequest unsubscribeFromNetworkReachabilityNotifications] in ASIHTTPRequest.o

(null): Symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

To solve this issue:
I renamed reachability class.
It is working fine on the device.
But it's giving the following error when I build on IOS simulator.

```
1. ld: warning: ignoring file /Work_Theme_iPhone/New M_Caddie/MeetingCaddie/iOS_Eventpedia/TurnOutNow_SDK/libEventAnalytics.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Work_Theme_iPhone/New M_Caddie/MeetingCaddie/iOS_Eventpedia/TurnOutNow_SDK/libEventAnalytics.a (2 slices)
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_EASDK", referenced from:

```
2. (null): Ignoring file /Work_Theme_iPhone/New M_Caddie/MeetingCaddie/iOS_Eventpedia/TurnOutNow_SDK/libEventAnalytics.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Work_Theme_iPhone/New M_Caddie/MeetingCaddie/iOS_Eventpedia/TurnOutNow_SDK/libEventAnalytics.a (2 slices)
```

(null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EASDK", referenced from:

EASDK is a file in TurnoutNow  library.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: First thing i would try is to clean project (Product->Clean). If that does not help, it may be that `libEventsAnalytics.a` was not build for `i386` architecture, and not much you can do there.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But it is working on device and not on simulator. I checked if libEventsAnalytics.a architecture compatibility using lipo -info and it says armv7 aand arm64.

Answer (score 0):

After going to several of link, I found that

```
i386 = ios simulator or 32 bit build on mac os x
armv6 armv7 arm7s = ios device
x86_64 = 64 bit build on mac os x
```

and when I ran following command :
libEventAnalytics.a (for architecture cputype (16777228) cpusubtype (0)):   current ar archive random library
Amits-Mac-mini:TurnOutNow_SDK achavan$ lipo -info libEventAnalytics.a 
Architectures in the fat file: libEventAnalytics.a are: armv7 arm64

I found that  libEventAnalytics.a is not built for i386 and x86_64.
So I am unable to run my app on simulator.